# Why can't I fill a UIBezierPath with custom UIColor?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to fill a `UIBezierPath` with my custom color, but only the default colors like `UIColor.redColor` or `UIColor.blueColor` are working.

Here is my code:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let layerHeight = self.layer.frame.height
    let layerWidth = self.layer.frame.width
    let width:CGFloat = 50

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(layerWidth, layerHeight))
    bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(layerWidth, layerHeight - width))
    bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(layerWidth - width, layerHeight))
    bezierPath.closePath()

    // UIColor.blueColor().setFill() works, but a custom color does not:
    UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 23, green: 34, blue: 200, alpha: 1).setFill()
    bezierPath.fill()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong values. [The color values have to be in range 0.0 - 1.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:):

```
UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.2, green: 0.3, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1)
```

I would then recommend to use a slightly different initializer instead:

```
UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
```

What happened previously in your code is that all values above 1.0 are treated as 1.0, therefore together forming white, which you probably did not *see* as filling anything.

Comment: Oh my god so embarrassing, but thank you :)

Comment: @JulianPomper congratz on your App btw, looks pretty neat and nicely designed!

Comment: Thank you very much! But that is an old version, I am currently working on the new version which looks much better I think! How did you find it :O?

Comment: @JulianPomper I looked at your profile where you have a link to its homepage. And since I am german I was able to understand all the texts. Btw when being on the Impressum page the link in the footer towards the Kontakt page is broken (404) ;)

Comment: aah ok thanks! I will change that :)